# Phone, People, Call History without tabs

Tags: android, android-contacts

When launching either of the following activities: "Phone", "People", "Call History", there is a tab ribbon at the bottom of the screen.

Is there some way to launch these separate activities *without* that tab ribbon? I.e. launch "Phone" without having "Phone", "People", "Call History" tabs at the bottom of the screen? Likewise for the other two?

Comment: "When launching either of the following activities: "Phone", "People", "Call History", there is a tab ribbon at the bottom of the screen" -- only on some devices. Device manufacturers can and do modify the behavior of Android and are welcome to render this stuff however they want.

Comment: Wow, did *not* know that. So, basically, aside from implementing this functionality myself, there's nothing I can do?

Comment: The best solution is to not worry about the problem, and allow the device-specific UI to behave as it does. Users are familiar with their device; they will be unfamiliar with your replacements for this key functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Will you consider adding this answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When launching either of the following activities: "Phone", "People", "Call History", there is a tab ribbon at the bottom of the screen

On some devices, that will be the case. It will not be the case for all devices.

The Phone app, which is responsible for this UI, is perhaps the single-most modified app in the whole AOSP. Outside of Nexus-series devices, most other devices will have an alternative implementation of this app, with the same (or enhanced) functionality, but the manufacturer's own UI. Some may use tabs. Some may not.

Now, outside of perhaps some grossly-broken devices, launching the right `Intent` should take you to the right piece of this UI (e.g., `ACTION_DIAL` should take  you to the dialer, not to the call log). However, control over how this is rendered is up to the device manufacturer.